# Using payable custom tokem

Tags: solidity, nft, payable

I'm creating an NFT game and I have a big question about payable.

Below I'm putting my code that I'm invoking a new Hero.

```
function invokeRandomHero() public payable {
    require(msg.value == 0.001 ether);
    uint randGenetic = _generateRandomGenetic();
    _invokeRandomHero(randGenetic);
  }
```

If you notice I'm using a test with the "Ether" coin, my question is, how can I do the same charge but with my own coin?
I'm going to create a contract for a new currency called for example "SLP" (example only, equal to axie).

How do I use this currency charge to perform the "summon a new hero" transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `payable` keyword is only useful when dealing with the blockchain's native asset/coin - in this case Ethers. You can't create own coins, you can only create your own tokens. So I assume you are meaning ERC20 tokens.

If you want to associate a token price for invoking the function, you should use the two staged transfer:

1. User approves for the contract to withdraw X amount of his tokens, with the `approve` function in ERC20
2. User notifies the contract the user wishes to buy something with tokens, and the contract withdraws the tokens from the user with the `transferFrom` function, and gives him his hero.

Tutorial of this two-phased token trade can be found for example here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/transfers-and-approval-of-erc-20-tokens-from-a-solidity-smart-contract/

Comment: Hi Lauri, thanks for fast answer.. I got it.. You have a code example about this? Thanks again :)

Comment: I remember now, I haven't seen in my studies yet a way to return the "balance" referring to the ERC20 (my token), if you have any examples I'll thank you very much!

Comment: Add a link to a tutorial which has all of this. But it's very easy to google for more such tutorials, if needed. This is a very common pattern